# Javascript/Node JS , when downloading a file how to check file size and download the first kilobyte of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Javascript/Node JS , when downloading a file how to check file size and download the first kilobyte of a file. check the size of the file and download the first kb of file cause I wanna hash it and thenc ompare the hash of first kb with hash of tje downloded file. of same size) then reject the download if the size and hash is same.else download the file and move on

## My code in downloading files to server

```
 var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

                request.get(url)
                    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
                    .on('close', callback);

            };

            final_list.forEach(function (str) {

                var filename = str.split('/').pop();

                console.log('------- Downloading ------- ' + filename);

                promises.push(new Promise(function p(resolve, reject) {

                    var checksum = generateChecksum(str);

                    console.log("Generated Check Sum :", checksum)

                    download(str, './public/server/img/' + filename, function () {

                        var stats = fs.statSync('./public/server/img/' + filename)

                        var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
                        var fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0


                        console.log('Finished Downloading' + " " + filename);

                        resolve(filename);

                    }); // add error callback also, call reject() on error
                }
                ));

            });`enter code here`
```

## basic download feature code

```
var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

        request.get(url)
            .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
            .on('close', callback);

    };

    final_list.forEach(function (str) {
        var filename = str.split('/').pop();

        console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

        download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
    });
```

Comment: Note sure what you're trying to do.  `fs.read()` lets you read the first 1k of a file.  `fs.stat()` gets you the filesize.

Comment: I only want to download like the first 10KB of a file @jfriend00.

Comment: Did you look at what `fs.read()` does.  It lets you read any set of bytes you want from a file, 1k, 10k, 100k, 2 bytes, whatever.  I did not recommend `fs.readFile()` which reads the whole file.  I recommended `fs.read()`.

Comment: I have update my code and question please check

Comment: can you post your answer so i can upvote

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but here's what you asked for.

[`fs.read()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) lets you read any set of bytes from any position in a file and any number of bytes.   You can easily read the first 10k bytes with that if you want.

`fs.stat()` gets you the filesize.

Reading first parts of a file, contents send in a Buffer object to the callback:

```
function readStartOfFile(filename, sizeToRead, callback) {
      fs.open(filename, 'r', (err, fd) => {
           if (err) {
              callback(err);
          } else {
              let newBuffer = Buffer.alloc(sizeToRead);
              // fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback
              fs.read(fd, newBuffer, 0, sizeToRead, 0, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
                  fs.close(fd);
                  if (err) {
                        callback(err)
                  } else {
                       callback(null, buffer);
                  }
              });
          }
      });
 }

 // sample usage
 readStartOfFile("somefile.txt", 1024 * 10, (err, buffer) => {
      if (err) {
          // handle error here
      } else {
          // use buffer here
      }
 });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199354/discussion-on-answer-by-jfriend00-javascript-node-js-when-downloading-a-file-h).